# Rational Right Triangle Problem & Elliptic Curves

Tags: number-theory

If we know the sides of a right triangle with rational sides and area=7, from this triangle, how can we get the right triangle with rational sides and area=14? Or the question can be the other way i.e. from 14 to 7?
The explanation may be related to elliptic curve theory.

Comment: This is a forum on mathematics and not philosophy that can be interpreted. Write the equation which must be solved.

Comment: Dear, whosoever you are, if you don't know the answer, you may not comment. But it is a mathematical problem and not a philosophical one. As mentioned, it is related to elliptic curve theory.

Comment: The fact that the area of a right triangle. $S=ps(p^2-s^2)$, where these numbers are integers. Rational can only be relative to the hypotenuse. This means that you can write a finite number of coprime solutions. Therefore, I say - in relation to what decisions should be rational? It is necessary to write equations. This can for example be interpreted. $ps(p^2-s^2)=7$ $kr(k^2-r^2)=14$   And in General what is the connection between these equations?

Comment: See [generating a Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) and [integer triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle) and [Heronian triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle).